# Bootstrap 4 - Navbar-toggler collapse works! However, if I change the stylesheet CSS on the fly, it does not work anymore?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a question and I would be very glad if someone could help me!
Please, if someone find the question stupid or not even well explained, please, before give a negative feedback, write bellow what should I improve. In this way, I can learn with my mistakes! Thanks in advance!

My webpage is composed only by javascript, jquery, CSS and bootstrap 4.
The problem is about the **Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger Menu**. **The navbar works without any problem**. However, **if I change the stylesheet (style.css) of my page on the fly it does not work anymore**. I changed **only** the stylesheet. I tried also to change the style to the **same** style sheet. I still got the same problem.
How I changed the stylesheet? Here:
My html code head:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css">
```

Then I have a button that when clicked change the style:

```
document.querySelector("#pagestyle").setAttribute("href", link);
```

**link** has the address of other style sheet as "./style/styleBig.css". The code above works without any warning or problem. I am able to change the stylesheet of my code throught ES6 without any problem. However, the hamburger navbar toggler stop working.

So, **after loading a new or even the same style sheet in my homepage the navbar hamburger menu stop to work**. It open but do not collapsed anymore... *Change the style on the fly means that you click a botton and the website load another stylesheet.*

Someone have any idea what it could be? Would I need to reload the jQuery again?

I see that the hamburger menu in the NAVBAR normally works like this (HTML CYCLE CHANGES):

**Stage (1)**: navbar OPEN -> html code:

`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">`

**To Stage (2)**: navbar trying to collapse -> html code: 

`<div class="navbar-collapse collapsing" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">`

**To Stage (3)**: navbar collapsed

`<div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">`

The problem as soon as I change the stylesheet on the fly, the navbar does not work. It means, as soon as I click in the hamburger menu, it changes from **stage 1 to 2** and comeback to **stage 1**. However, it should go to **stage 3**!

NAVBAR CODE:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

I could also program it by myself without using bootstrap, however, I really would like to understand why it stop to work after loading a new or even the same stylesheet. 
Could anyone please help!
**Thank you very much in advance!**
Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: What CSS exactly do both files contain, that affect the dropdown? Bootstrap itself uses quite some SCSS for [navs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8fa0d3010112dca5dd6dd501173415856001ba8b/scss/_nav.scss) and [navbars](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8fa0d3010112dca5dd6dd501173415856001ba8b/scss/_navbar.scss) so if the second file does not include those, that might be the source of your problem.

Comment: In any case, we cannot really help unless you show us the code that actually styles the dropdown. [Just create a working snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I hope it can help anyone in the future. The problem was in the another part of the code. I was reloading the jQuery as soon as I click in the page. I had implemented it before because it was not working very well on github server. I solved the problem of github but I got this problem of bootstrap. 
So, in this case I decided to **remove** this code below:

```
  (function() {
      let startingTime = new Date().getTime();
      // Load the script
      let script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
      let script2 = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
      script.src = "./lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js";
      script2.src = "./lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js";

      script.onload = function() {
        let $ = window.jQuery;
        $(function() {
              let endingTime = new Date().getTime();
              let tookTime = endingTime - startingTime;
              console.log("jQuery & Bootstrap is loaded dinamically, after " + tookTime + " milliseconds!" + "Test function only to try to solve github load problem.");
          });
      };
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script2);
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

  })();
```

So, as soon as I reload the jquery and bootstrap to try to solve another problem I got the problem with bootstrap. So, I decided to remove the code above **because it is clear that the solution above is not the way to go**! *We should not solve one problem and create another one*. So, I just remove the code above and it works fine. I will let the code here, it can be the problem of someone in the future and I would be glad if I can help someone!!
Thanks!